# Java Rounding to specific decimal places

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program that rounds to one decimal place less. For example if I have a total of 32.45678 it should be 32.4568 or if its 0 it should be 0.0. Here is what I have so far. Thanks

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class product{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");

    float f1 = scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number:");

    float f2 = scan.nextFloat();
    float p = f1*f2;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".####");
    System.out.println("Product: "+df.format(p));

  }

}
```

Comment: If it get 0 it does not format it to 0.0, am I missing something in my code?

Comment: `if (n == 0) { return "0.0"; }`

Comment: You've done it. What's the question?

Comment: Its still wont format properly when I have 59.73243 * 243.434 =14540.9044, it wont format to 14540.904. This is my last issue.  :(

Comment: Why do you expect `14540.904`? Shouldn't it be `14540.9044`?

Comment: It should round to one decimal place less, so if I have 14540.9044 it should be 14540.904.

Comment: If I am round to thousandths place in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The textual entered number 32.456 or 32.456432234 could become a float 32.45600004 or 32.456432. As floats and doubles are just approximations.

One could use BigDecimal as `new BigDecimal("32.456")` will have a precision (scale) of 3. The most satisfying solution IMO. So read the tokens as String.

One could read Strings, determine their precision, do a `Float.parseFloat` and format them to the decremented precision desired. A format for output would need to be made for that precision.

```
String s1 = scan.next();
BigDecimal f1 = new BigDecimal(s1);
int scale = f1.scale(); // 25E3 == 25000 with scale -3.
if (scale < 1) {
    scale = 1;
} else {
    --scale;
}
f1 = f1.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

---

***A suggestion more***

```
Maybe you wanted just to round a bit more. (Doubting the last digit?)

float f1 = ...;
String s = Float.toString(f1);
if (s.contains("E")) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
if (s.contains(".")) {
   s += ".0";
} else {
   char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
   if (c >= '5') {
       char d = s.charAt(s.length() - 2);
       s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2) + ((char) (d + 1));
   } else {
       s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
   }
}
return s;
```

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: @5ktm5 depends on your needs, BigDecimal is a bit awkward, but good at financial software and such. Added a do-it-yourself rounding, either of any float, or a string as input.